# Why does the timezone pattern "OOOO" not show the full GMT+00:00 offset format?

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, timezone-offset, java-time

### Is this a bug or a feature?

The [`DateTimeFormatter` JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) explicitly states that when I use the `OOOO` pattern in my formatter, the **full form** of localized timezone should be used (emphasis mine):

> Four letters outputs the full form, which is localized offset text, such as 'GMT, **with 2-digit hour and minute field**, optional second field if non-zero, and colon, for example 'GMT+08:00'.

But in case the time is in GMT+0:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.SSS OOOO");

String timestamp = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneOffset.UTC).format(formatter);
System.out.println(timestamp);
```

This is the output:

```
Mon 2019.02.25 22:30:00.586 GMT
```

Expected:

```
Mon 2019.02.25 22:30:00.586 GMT+00:00
```

Comment: It's not exactly direct, but the `Z` specifier says "The output will be the corresponding localized offset text if the offset is zero". It would be odd if this resulted in `GMT+0000`, since that would just be `Z` with non-zero offset; in other words, there would be no need to call that out as a special case.

Comment: A strict reading of the javadoc indicates, to me at least, that `OOOO` is only guaranteed to produce “the full form, which is localized offset text.”  An *example* given is “GMT, with 2-digit hour and minute field, optional second field if non-zero, and colon,” but I don’t read it as *guaranteeing* that the full form includes a colon or hour/minute.  It can be argued that Zulu time has no offset.

Comment: I have reproduced on Java 8, 10 and 11. The observed behaviour doesn’t agree with the way I read the docs either. If the offset is something else than 0, I get the expected, for example `GMT+02:00`.

Comment: @OleV.V. If any other method also contains the same check, it might have been the result of a sleepy copy-paste, therefore a bug. Anyway, I want my +00:00 somehow.

Comment: @VGR It explicitly states that the second field is optional, it does not for hour and minute, which would make them non-optional IMO.

Comment: Reading it again, I think you might be right.  I wonder if it’s a documentation defect, since as Ole V.V. points out, the decision was deliberate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bug? We seem to agree that the observed behaviour does not agree with the documentation (or at least you will have to do a very creative reading of the documentation to make it match).

A feature? As far as I can tell the observed behaviour is a conscious decision at some point. The source code for the private inner class `LocalizedOffsetIdPrinterParser` inside `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` contains `if (totalSecs != 0) {` before printing hours, minutes and seconds. It doesn’t look like a copy-paste error since the exact same code line is nowhere else in the file (offset 0 is treated specially in a number of places, but I am not aware of anywhere else it is left out completely).

On Java 8 format pattern `OOOO` neither parses `GMT` alone nor `GMT+00:00`, which must be a bug. It’s fixed in Java 11. On Java 11 `OOOO` parses `GMT` alone just fine, so they must have considered this acceptable (it parses `GMT+00:00` and `GMT-00:00` too, though).

You may consider filing a bug with Oracle and/or OpenJDK (I’m unsure about the right place these days). Whether they will reject it, fix the documentation or fix the code — I dare not try to guess.

**Workaround: 'GMT'xxx**

> Anyway, I want my +00:00 somehow.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.SSS 'GMT'xxx");
```

> Wed 2019.02.27 08:46:43.226 GMT+00:00

Comment: **YES!** Thank you for the work-around. In my case, I will be using the `'GMT'xxxxx` timezone pattern, which works perfectly well too: `Wed 2019.02.27 15:32:59.347 GMT+00:00`.

Comment: Since the "bug" was in Oracle docs, I have reported it to them. Let's see what happens..

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug.

The Java specification follows LDML (CLDR). See [here](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#dfst-zone) for the definition of "OOOO" and [here](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Using_Time_Zone_Names) for the definition of "localized GMT format":

> Localized GMT format: A constant, specific offset from GMT (or UTC), which may be in a translated form. There are two styles for this. The first is used when there is an explicit non-zero offset from GMT; this style is specified by the  element and  element. The long format always uses 2-digit hours field and minutes field, with optional 2-digit seconds field. The short format is intended for the shortest representation and uses hour fields without leading zero, with optional 2-digit minutes and seconds fields. The digits used for hours, minutes and seconds fields in this format are the locale's default decimal digits:
>
> "GMT+03:30" (long)
>
> "GMT+3:30" (short)
>
> "UTC-03.00" (long)
>
> "UTC-3" (short)
>
> "Гриинуич+03:30" (long)
>
> Otherwise (when the offset from GMT is zero, referring to GMT itself) the style specified by the  element is used:
>
> "GMT"
>
> "UTC"
>
> "Гриинуич"

Since the offset from GMT is zero, the bottom clause applies, and the output is just "GMT" (or whatever is the correct localized text for your locale).

Hopefully the Javadoc can be clarified in a future release.